# What does it exactly mean by information management as a function of O/s

Tags: data-structures, operating-systems, information-theory

I have read that information management is a function of O/s by which it

A) Manages, stores, retrieves,modify data. It makes sure that right people have access to their information.

B) Some of the system calls in this category are as follows:

1. Create a file
2. Open a file (for, read, write or both).
3. Create a directory
4. Read data from file to buffer
5. Close a file
6. Read and return file's status
7. Move the file pointer
8. Change working directory
9. Create a link
10. Write data from buffer to file

The definitions,system call information is from textbook.

Now, after understand this.  There was no example in my textbook which showed how does this information management looks like. So, I have created certain examples. I want to confirm whether what I have understand is correct or not.

The point A refers to:

1. How we note down information in Notepad,MS excel in these application on our computer. When we check the memory,it will show how much information of data in GB,KB etc is filled in the computer.
2. Password is another form of information management. Without knowing password of a computer, we cannot access the information on that computer.

From point B,

1. We can create files in the computer & open them or close whenever we want. By creating different files, we can arrange our data better.[image]

The file icon that I am talking about.

Have I understood & given write examples for information management in O/s?

Comment: PS, its OS (Operating System), not "O/s".

Comment: @nirshahar In my textbook, it is written like that,